# Finding the extreme points in picture using openCV

Tags: python, opencv

The challenge: I want to use the edges highlighted by the green dots to crop the image. I need to locate the points, and then use that to crop.

What I've done: I've tried to use threshold to get to the point where I eliminate the rest of the picture and only highlight the corner points and it works. Only issue is that I can't find a way to highlight the edge (the ones in green in the second picture) as the outermost pixel. All the techniques I'm reading up on use contours, but because these become independent dots, connected components seems better in theory. I am however stumped how to use connected components for this task.

Here is the original picture:
[image]

Here is the picture with the green dots illustrating the corners of interest:
[image]

Here is the picture after threshold:
[image]

Clearly contouring won't work. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Perhaps find the 4 fiducial marks by 4 template matches with 90 rotated templates. Then sort the 4 points and draw rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using morphology is a good idea. I will supplement **Basj's** answer with the code and the result:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("XfRte.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(7,7))
img_open = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
coord=cv2.boundingRect(img_open)
img_crop=img[coord[1]:coord[3]+coord[1], coord[0]:coord[2]+coord[0]]
cv2.imwrite('ans.png', img_crop)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Is it possible to add something about the size of the blob? such that if like someone adds a small ink stain on the side of the paper, it doesn't throw off the process?

Comment: You can filter objects by size and area using the function cv2.connectedComponentWithStats(). Or you can use fmw42 's idea.

Comment: I just ran a sample and simply increased the parameter in getStructuringElement to 8 instead of 7 and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the symbols you are trying to recognize are the *thickest* symbols on this picture, you can use an "Erosion" followed by a "Dilation". This is called an "Opening".

Do this on a copy `img2` of your image `img`, after these steps you will have only the 4 symbols you're looking for. Then you easily find the coordinates. Based on the coordinates, you can then crop your original image `img`.

All this is available directly in Python OpenCV.

If the colors are inversed, you might try the same operation in the reverse order.

See [Morphological Transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers: makes sense. How do you find the coordinates if you only have the 4 symbols left? @basj

Comment: @Sam Then you can split the image in 4 parts (upper left, upper right, lower left, lower right). Then on each part, you can findContour (it will be super easy because only your symbol will be remaining), take the coordinates of the only 1 contour you'll get, and then `min(x), min(y)` for the upper left, `max(x), min(y)` for the upper right, etc.

Comment: @Sam The important thing is to do the erosion + dilation with the *right* parameter, you have to experiment with value 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc. until you find the good parameter that removes the unwanted lines and keeps the big symbols you're interested in.

Comment: I like the idea of splitting the image, but this doesn't sound efficient. I have to do this over and over for about 1,200 of these at a time. Is there a more efficient suggestion?

Comment: @Sam It is *totally* efficient. When you have a numpy array `x` of size 1000x1000 for example, working on `x[0:500, 0:500]`, `x[500:1000, 0:500]`, etc. *doesn't copy* the data in memory into new objects, instead it is only a *view* (read https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html). TL;DR no data is duplicated.